# Is there a limit of two images within Stack Overflow answer content to a "New Contributor"?

Tags: discussion

When I answered a question, I could only add two images.
If I added one third image I couldn't submit a message, because I get the form error warning:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
> code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
> or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
> toolbar icon.

Is it because I'm a *"New Contributor"*?